# Sharing a created Google form with linked sheet for others to use

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, sharing, google-workspace, file-sharing

I have created several systems with Google Forms (and linked sheets) to log services provided and timekeeping. I would like to share these systems with other people to use as a template for their own data. Is there a way to easily do this keeping my formula's intact?

**Successfully:** I have found a way to share the form only as a template by copying the URL into an emailed hyperlink changing the ending from edit to copy.

**Cumbersome but ok Migrant Service Log:** This method does not seem to work entirely for spreadsheets. It still asks me to give them access to the original document. I can set access on the original to view only and limit the time to one day.

**Unsuccessful Clock In/Out:** The new "copy" of the spreadsheet is not automatically linked with new "copy" of the Forms so it does not update when a new response is added. I must link it in form. This becomes more of an issue with my sheets that have formulas based on these responses. It is now necessary for each new user to manually link and rename the sheets to make them function correctly.

*Clock In/Out System (attendance purposes)*
[Clock In Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1FfPRp3UNThjgio6ZjGpEY-IhHqFy7hbFEbxnrB2EDdQ/copy)
[Clock Out Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1K-x-lfzrWr2XjMLkREmpf9qbZTJslhCQ5Cy7OyQMXtw/copy)
[MSA Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1psnvR4wSLuHSs_aeLoMcTo3bD9sF1uqk8BzboqpIQlI/copy)
[Attendance Office Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cBDY7abQTeMsLhK_tCtSp0M087t0l6ScyhOoDQLx2Lw/copy)

*Migrant Service Log (team communication purposes)*
[Migrant Service Log Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1XYEhctzqajArxRxLJ3nwZcqrFiC1aUrRZYY-rq8vFHM/copy)
[Migrant Service Log Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12UCrY4pXoJVKDeyKl6sHqaeR4iZSIq8OEpjHWeaZedU/copy)

I would like for them to all be user-friendly and easily shared while keeping everything confidential to the user.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep your formulas as a secret you can set up the 2nd spreadsheet and use `IMPORTRANGE` formula to get data over and then just simply link the 2nd spreadsheet somewhere on the end of the form.

Comment: It is not so much as keeping my formulas a secret. I would like to give the entire system over to many different users without them being able to see my confidential data, or me being able to see theirs. As in I use IMPORTRANGE in the Attendance office sheet and it is still linked to my original form, and does not update to link to the "Copy" form.